# Where can I find the source code for Html.EditorFor online?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I started looking for this, I downloaded the MVC from codeplex but still can't find it. I would like to try and understand some of the code relating to check boxes.

Is this code for Html.EditorFor available some place online?

Answer (score 5):

The source code for MVC-3 is available from [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) (codeplex.com). The Html.EditorFor extension methods are in `mvc3-rtm-sources/mvc3/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/Html/EditorExtensions.cs`.

Comment: +1 - Also, MSDN here if it helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor.aspx